# PHP condition doesn't work

Tags: php, conditional-statements, sha

I have this code

```
$nick = $_POST["user"];
$pass = sha1($_POST["pass"]);

$user = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM users");
$user = pg_fetch_object($user);

if($user->nick != $nick || $user->pass != $pass) {
    echo 'Wrong user or password';
}
```

nick in database is character type and is quite hashed, but I still get 'Wrong user or password' on output.

Is there any type conflict?

Comment: You're only getting the first record in your code. What if the record is the second one? You can add the checks to your SQL - `SELECT * FROM users WHERE nick=? AND pass=?`, and then bind the parameters before executing the query

Comment: That's the kind of approach where the database is tortured with endless requests that always return the maximum amount of available data and then the application fails to find the one dataset that it is looking for. Hint: `"SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE nick = ? AND pass = ?"`

Comment: I know, it returns all records in table, but I've only 1 there. And I tested, what query return, and it seems right.

Comment: Well, now i find, what can by problem, in strings from database has space on the end etc. "pass ", but in POSTs not, that can causes the false result of condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$nick = $_POST["user"];
$pass = sha1($_POST["pass"]);

$user = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE nick = '$nick' and pass='$pass'");
$num = pg_num_rows($user);
$user = pg_fetch_object($user);

if($num==0) {
    echo 'Wrong user or password';
}
```

When do query with some value that the client will interact, make sure he will not use some methods of injection

Change code:

```
$nick = pg_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST["user"]));
$pass = sha1($_POST["pass"]);
```